# Can't return an array of addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm trying to get all the products (their addresses) belonging to a specific Handler but can't get it to work... It compiles fine, returns the `_name` and `_additionalInformation` properly but not `_ownerProducts`, I don't know why...

```
address[] public products;

// struct which represents a Handler for the products stored in the 
database.
struct Handler {
// indicates the name of a Handler.
string _name;
// Additional information about the Handler, generally as a JSON object
string _additionalInformation;
// All products owned by the Handler
address[] _ownerProducts;
}

//  Relates an address with a Handler record.
mapping(address => Handler) public addressToHandler;

/*  Constructor to create a Database */
function Database() {}

function () {
// If anyone wants to send Ether to this contract, the transaction gets rejected
throw;
}

/*  Function to add a Handler reference
  _address address of the handler
  _name The name of the Handler
  _additionalInformation Additional information about the Product,
        generally as a JSON object.
  _ownerProducts All the products owned by the Handler */

function addHandler(address _address, string _name, string _additionalInformation, address[] _ownerProducts) onlyOwner {
Handler memory handler;
handler._name = _name;
handler._additionalInformation = _additionalInformation;
handler._ownerProducts = _ownerProducts;

addressToHandler[_address] = handler;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to get the data from public `mapping`?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the data form the `struct` for each addresses mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    function getHandler(address _ad) view public returns(string,string,address[]){
        return (addressToHandler[_ad]._name,addressToHandler[_ad]._additionalInformation,addressToHandler[_ad]._ownerProducts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is not a valid case. As per the solidity documentation regarding getters of public states:

> If you have a public state variable of array type, then you can only
>   retrieve single elements of the array via the generated getter
>   function. This mechanism exists to avoid high gas costs when returning
>   an entire array. You can use arguments to specify which individual
>   element to return, for example data(0). If you want to return an
>   entire array in one call, then you need to write a function.

You need to define a function for that like this:

```
// function that returns entire array
  function getArray(address _addr) public view returns (address[] memory) {
      return addressToHandler[_addr]._ownerProducts;
  }
```

This function is working on Remix.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you for the function, it works indeed!